# Find line containing more than 3 numbers (Regex)

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have thousands of rows in my text file, and i would like to know if there is a way using Notepad (regex) to find and select only the lines that contain more than 3 numbers each !

Thank you in advance !

Comment: What is your understanding of a number? Single digit, multiple digits, decimal, floating point? is `a1234b` matching your criterion of more than three numbers? Or must it be `a 123 456 789`?

Comment: multiple digits on next to another one, in a row like this : ae13823698541@kjqk     so any line that has a lot of digits inside the row should be marked and removed ! (there are no decimal or float numbers)  But these numbers can be inside between strings !

Comment: So basically your regex would be `^.*\d{4}.*$` which means every line, which contains at least 4 consecutive digits, regardless what comes before or after (`.*` means match basically anything)

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer did solved perfectly my problem. That's exactly what i needed, it does select the numbers within a long string. How can i select your answer as the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

If the numbers are integers, and there can be other (non-digit) characters separating these integers, you can use something like this to match the lines:

```
^(?=(\D*\d+(\D+|$)){4,}).*$
```

Explanation:

- `^` matches the start of the line
- `(?=` means the following must match (positive lookahead)

  - `\D*\d+(\D+|$)` matches any number of non-digits, followed by your number, followed by some non-digit separator (or the end of the line, if nothing comes after the last number)
  - `{4,}` matches the above pattern at least 4 times
- `.*` captures the entire line, as long as the positive lookahead above is matched (i.e. there are more than 3 numbers)
- `$` matches the end of the line

If the numbers can have decimals, you can replace the `\d+` with something like `(\d+\.?\d*)` to match `3`, `3.`, `3.456`, etc:

```
^(?=(\D*(\d+\.?\d*)(\D+|$)){4,}).*$
```

e.g.

- `1.2 3.456 7 8.90` matches
- `12/34/56/78/90` matches
- `some 1 text 2 in 3 between 4 the 5 numbers` matches
- `1 2 3` doesn't match